# Is gifting games on Origin region locked?

Tags: origin, anthem

My friend from the US wants to force me to play Anthem by gifting it to me in india, the question is that is the gifting system region locked? i can't find any concrete answer in the [FAQs on the origin website](https://help.ea.com/en-in/help/origin/origin/send-and-receive-gifts-with-origin/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes,There is no way to gift games across regions.We tried it and it failed. He ended up making a new account, buying the game on it and then sending me the account login details. It really is a visually impressive game.

Comment: "It really is a visually impressive game." Unfortunately, that's the only impressive thing about Anthem.